# Azure Site-To-Site VPN with Oracle OCI

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, azure-vpn

I am trying to connect to Oracle cloud infrastructure from Azure using azure S2S VPN and it's not getting connected.

I have already created policy-based route that's supports IKEv1 because oracle OCI only supports IKEv1. Please find here the parameters from oracle side:

[image: Oracle OCI parameters]

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The above is the configuration of Azure VPN gateway. On checking, it seems like PFS needs to be disabled on your end as Azure Policy based gateway doesn't support.

If that doesn't fix the issue, please post the IKE/IPSEC logs to further troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there a way that we can change the configuration from Azure side instead of Oracle. I mean enabling PFS from azure instead disabling it from Oracle because oracle side configuration cannot be change according to oracle vendor.

Comment: For policy based gateway this configuration cannot be changed. If this is the case, you need to look into NVAs available in market place.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback do you have any recommendation on NVAs

Comment: You can go with Cisco NVAs. It comes with multiple flavours. Please go through the docs and choose the one which meets your requirements.